# JavaScript: how to calculate values using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have following JSON data and trying to calculate the total price of each year:

```
const data = [
  { year: 2020, price: 400 },
  { year: 2019, price: 20 },
  { year: 2020, price: 100 },
  { year: 2019, price: 80 },
]
```

I wrote the following code to calculate the price but the result is incorrect.

```
const price = data.reduce((acc, current) => {

  if(!acc[current.year]) {
    acc[current.year] =  current.price;
  }

  acc[current.year] += current.price;

  return acc;

}, {});
```

How do I fix the code and what's my problem?

Also, are the following meaning same? I don't understand the syntax of (acc[item.color] || 0) part.

```
const test1 = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.color] = (acc[item.color] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

```
const test2 = data.reduce((acc, item) => {

  if(!acc[item.color]) {
    acc[item.color] = 0;
  }

  acc[item.color] = acc[item.color] + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: What happens in your code if the if statement succeeds?

Comment: `const price = clothes.reduce((acc, current) => {` should you not have `data.reduce`?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, btw where is `item.color`. It is not present in the dataset i.e `data`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, 'clothes' was supposed to be data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are adding the value of `current.price` twice when you don't already have a key `acc[current.year]`.

```
const data = [
  { year: 2020, price: 400 },
  { year: 2019, price: 20 },
  { year: 2020, price: 100 },
  { year: 2019, price: 80 },
]

const price = data.reduce((acc, current) => {

  if(!acc[current.year]) {
    acc[current.year] =  0;
  }

  acc[current.year] += current.price;

  return acc;

}, {});
```

> Also, are the following meaning same? I don't understand the syntax of (acc[item.color] || 0) part.

In this `acc[item.color] || 0` means `OR` between the value of `acc[item.color]` and `0`. When the value of `acc[item.color]` is not null or undefined the result of `acc[item.color] || 0` will be the value of `acc[item.color]`.

Otherwise if the value of `acc[item.color]` is undefined or null, `null || 0` will return 0.

So, `acc[item.color] = (acc[item.color] || 0) + 1` this means set the value of `acc[item.color]` to `acc[item.color]` if it is defined otherwise set to `0`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So ``acc[current.year] =  0;`` <- is this like initializing the value of ``acc[current.year]`` ? If I write ``acc[current.year] =  current.price;`` what will be the value of ``current.price``? Like 400?

Comment: Glad you understood it. Yes this is initializing the value of `acc[current.year]` to `0`, so that you can perform `acc[current.year] += current.price;` this operation. Otherwise if you don't initialize the value of `acc[current.year]` then `acc[current.year] += current.price;` this will return `NaN`, because it will add `current.price` to `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, if we do `acc[current.year] =  current.price;` then this will set the value of `acc[current.year]` to `current.price`. It will set `acc[2020] = 400`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `reduce` on `clothes` instead `data`.

You just need to add `else`, Everything else is perfect. You are adding the `current.price` if `acc[current.year]` is not there.

```js
const data = [
  { year: 2020, price: 400 },
  { year: 2019, price: 20 },
  { year: 2020, price: 100 },
  { year: 2019, price: 80 },
];

const price = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  if (!acc[current.year]) {
    acc[current.year] = current.price;
  } else acc[current.year] += current.price;

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(price);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought ``acc[current.year] += current.price;`` was automatically executed even if I don't write else statement. So in ``acc[current.year] = current.price;``, current.price = 0?

Comment: This statement `acc[current.year] += current.price;` is executed always in your code @kayak . But the problem is that if you don't have an else, then the value of `current.price` will be added to `acc[current.year]` twice, when the `if` block is executed. Once in the `if` block and once during executing `acc[current.year] += current.price;`.